# Need to rephrase a CSV column (Containing both long & lat) to create a series of leaflet polyline coordinates for geojson

Tags: javascript, php, csv, leaflet

I am creating a leaflet based app and need to create many polylines from a csv file. Both Long and Lat coordinates are put into a single cell.

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-CIabXF2ROPKb-vGmqXNpMCrK4gqjrPDGsj7UGwh_8w/edit?usp=sharing

I need to convert the data in the "Coordinates" cell
 from: `10 -11 12 -13 23 -34` to `[10,-11],[12,-13],[23,-34]`  as so that it can be understood as long and lat coodinates by geojson.

How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 2 functions together.

1. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php to read the csv into a variable.
2. then you can explode the last item of the (1) call with these function https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php `explode("\n", $csvfield)`